# Word Macro - auto increment invoice number and file name on save

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, macros

We're developing an invoice template for Word, which contains an invoice number in a field at the top of the page.

We would like the invoice number to auto-increment (from the last invoice number), and we would like the filename to be based on the invoice number.

They'll all be saved in the same directory.

Comment: I do not understand why someone has down voted you; this question is no worse than many others.  Your question implies you hope to do this all in Word.  I would use Access (which has auto-increment) so I could pull in things like customer name and address from tables and keep a usable record of my invoices.  Finally I would output to Word if that was how I wanted to print my invoices.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Some people are judgemental nazis, myself probably included...  :-P

Comment: @Tony/Steve: I think it may have been voted down as the tone is as though someone is simply asking a forum member to make it for them. I posted a question where someone pointed this out to me, and I get it now. Post a question but don't treat people on here like their your butler. No offence.

Comment: @Mike. I see your point. I did not read the question that way although, on reflection, with the remarks about filenames and use of a single directory perhaps I should have. I read it as a question about auto-incrementing in Word.  I can think of some very clumsy ways of doing so but as I said I would not even try.  To me, this looks to be an easy Access macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/NumberDocs.htm) which I think will solve the problem:

> Use an Autonew macro to add a sequential number to a document and save
>   it with that number.
>
> In the template from which you create the document, insert a bookmark
>   named Order in the location where you want the sequential number to
>   appear and create an AutoNew macro in the template, as follows:
>
> ```
> Sub AutoNew()
>
> Order = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Settings.Txt", _
>         "MacroSettings", "Order")
>
> If Order = "" Then
>     Order = 1
> Else
>     Order = Order + 1
> End If
>
> System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Settings.txt", "MacroSettings", _
>         "Order") = Order
>
> ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Order").Range.InsertBefore Format(Order, "00#")
> ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="path" & Format(Order, "00#")
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> If you don't need to display the number in the document, but just want
>   to save it with a sequential number, there is no need to create the
>   bookmark in the template and you should then delete the second last
>   line of the code.

Comment: I said I could think of clumsy ways of doing this so I am pleased your website didn't recommend a smooth way that I had overlooked.  Good luck if you can make this work but I still think this is a really difficult way of achieving your objective.

Comment: 10 seconds to copy and paste the macro, and the only pitfall is a text file is required to store the incremental number.  Not difficult at all.  Not intellectually elegant, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub GoGenInv()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="BkMrk_InvNum"
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=10, Extend:=wdExtend
    Dim nInvNum As Variant
    nInvNum = Val(Selection.Text)
    nInvNum = nInvNum + 1
    Selection.Text = nInvNum
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="BkMrk_InvNum"
End Sub
```

Comment: Code only answers are appreciated, but can be subject to deletion.  Can you please explain how and why this is the answer to the question?

Comment: Please explain how this works, and how a user would use it. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. P.S. You don’t need to delete and re-post a post to fix a problem; just [edit] it.